# Bootstrap 2 - is the grid column wrapping behaviour the same as Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, multiple-columns, grid-layout, word-wrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

Bootstrap's grid system is based on a 12-column layout, and in the current version (3.3.5), "if more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line."

However, I'm updating a site that uses an old version of Bootstrap (2.3.2) and the docs don't mention anything about column wrapping. Can I rely on the same column wrapping behaviour with Bootstrap 2.3.2?

Answer (score 0):

Surely also in BootStrap 2, if you try to put more than 12 columns in a single row, elements wrap but with left margin starting on second row. The behaviour is the same because both are based on `float:left` positioning